# How to pass on a filename as a variable between PHP-files?

Tags: php, xml

I have this **file1.php**:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php
$path_to_check = '';
$needle = $_POST['query'];

foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.xml') as $filename)
{
  foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
  {
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      echo $filename . ' on line ' . ($fli+1) . ': ' . $fl;
    }
  }
}
$_SESSION["hit"] = $fli;
header('Location: file2.php');
?>
```

It gets a searchword from a form and searchs for it among all XML-files in the current directory. The XML-files in this directory are only two; 1.xml and 2.xml.

Say I search for a word occuring in 2.xml, then I would like to save "2.xml" as the variable $_SESSION["hit"] and use it in **file2.php**:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php
echo $_SESSION["hit"];
// Load XML file
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load($_SESSION["hit"]);

// Load XSL file
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('stylesheet.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

// Attach the xsl rules
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

Unfortunately,

```
echo $_SESSION["hit"];
```

returns just "2" and not "2.xml", so then

```
$xml->load($_SESSION["hit"]);
```

will not load the XML-file 2.xml (since the variable just returns 2).

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

Comment: `$fli` is a number of line and not a file name.

Comment: I changed it to $filename and the echo $_SESSION["hit"]; now correctly returns '2.xml'. However it will not get passed on in $xml->load($_SESSION["hit"]); Maybe it's wrong syntax to pass on the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php
$path_to_check = '';
$needle = $_POST['query'];

foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.xml') as $filename)
{
  foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
  {
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      echo $filename . ' on line ' . ($fli+1) . ': ' . $fl;
      $_SESSION["hit"] = $filename;
    }
  }
}

header('Location: file2.php');
?>
```

you need to save the file name in session variable not the line number

Comment: If you don't need to look for the other files once you find the `$needle`, add `break;` after assigning a value to `$_SESSION["hit"]`.

Comment: That made it Tehseen ULLAH. I also omitted the line 'echo $filename . ' on line ' . ($fli+1) . ': ' . $fl;' It has no purpose. Thank you!